# I need to handle only the column names of the specific selected table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I select a table from `ComboBox` I get every column that exists in that table(and a option to hide it when I check it).

[image]

When I select the next table from 'combobox' I get the new table columns plus the previous from the first table.

[image]

How can I fix that and save only the selected table columns?

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tableName = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}", form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True"));
    dataTable = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dataTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(column.HeaderText);
        var item2 = comboBox2.Items.Add(column.HeaderText);
        item.Tag = column.Name;
        item.Checked = column.Visible;
        item.CheckOnClick = true;

        item.CheckedChanged += (obj, args) =>
        {
            var i = (ToolStripMenuItem)obj;
            dataGridView1.Columns[(string)i.Tag].Visible = i.Checked;
        };
    }            
}
```

Comment: Call `contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear()` before filling it ( before `foreach`).

Comment: I can't believe it.... Thank you. :)

Comment: No problem ;) Also pay attention to the better way of clearing items collection which is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: By the way, I see you are creating a new instance of `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlConnection` every time that `SelectedIndexChanged` event happens and you are assigning it to some form fields which is not good idea. Instead use `using` statement for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the `Items` collection of `contextMenuStrip1` before filling it. It could be simply done by `contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear()`, however to prevent a probable handle/memory leak in your application, it's better to dispose the menu items right after removing them:

```
var items = contextMenuStrip1.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().ToList();
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
items.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());
```

**Example**

Here is a working example which needs a `DataGridView`, a `ComboBox` and a `ContextMenuStrip`. It loads tables of a database into the `ComboBox` and when you select an index from `ComboBox`, it loads data of the selected table into the `DataGridView` and if you right click on the column headers of the `DataGridView`, a `ContextMenuStrip` will be shown which allows you to set visibility of the columns:

```
string server = ".";
string db = "TestDB";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={db};Integrated Security=true";

    //Hanlde combo box selected index changed
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (obj1, args1) =>
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
          //Fill data table and show data in data grid view
          var data = GetDataTable($"SELECT * FROM {comboBox1.SelectedValue}", connection);
          dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
          dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }

        //Clear existing items of context menu strip
        var items = contextMenuStrip1.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().ToList();
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
        items.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());

        //Add the columns to context menu strip
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(c.HeaderText);
            item.Tag = c.Name;
            item.Checked = c.Visible;
            item.CheckOnClick = true;
            //Hanlde CheckStateChanged event of context menu strip items
            item.CheckStateChanged += (obj, args) =>
            {
                var i = (ToolStripMenuItem)obj;
                dataGridView1.Columns[(string)i.Tag].Visible = i.Checked;
            };
        }
    };

    //Load table names
    var tables = GetDataTable("SELECT Name FROM Sys.Tables", connection);
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.DataSource = tables;

    //Show context menu strip on right click on data grid veiw header
    dataGridView1.CellMouseClick += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.RowIndex == -1 && args.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
    };
}

DataTable GetDataTable(string commandText, string connectionString)
{
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, connectionString))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```